# Facebook not reading OpenGraph tags correctly

Tags: html-parsing, facebook-opengraph

- I am sharing reviews from my page and set the OpenGraph tags according to the rules on OGP[dot]ME
- If you go by the Parser @ www[dot]opengraph[dot]in/ then I am specifying my Open Graph tags correctly

The reviews on my page are shared as shortened URLs. Here are some examples:
1) http://bit[dot]ly/vOjQTV 
2) http://bit[dot]ly/srdsGR

When I attempt to share them on Facebook, the OpenGraph tags are not being read. 
Any suggestions as to why?
Why would the Open Graph Parser correctly read the tags and the Facebook parser not?

Comment: Fix has been pushed and the issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the OpenGraph URL tag. Once I fixed how that was set, the new FB Debugger tool & FB picked up all the OG Tags correctly.